# How can I dynamically widen navbar when user is on certain page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a project that uses a Wordpress plugin called LearnDash. Within this plugin a navbar was created containing links to certain lessons. These lessons go up to Lesson 15.

Now the issue that I am having is that Lessons 14 and 15 start on a separate line below Lessons 1 - 13 which is outside of this navbar. How can I get this navbar to widen dynamically, when the user is on this particular page?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage WP_Forge
 * @since WP-Forge 5.5.0.1
 */

namespace hmba;
include 'page-templates/HMBA_Funcs.php';

/* catch errors and report if in local enviorment. */
if (isLocalhost()) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

function getLessonNav($pillars, $pillarCurrent, $lessonCurrent) {
    foreach ($pillars as $key => $pillar) {
        if (strpos($pillar['url'], $pillarCurrent) && array_key_exists('lessons', $pillar)) {
            return $pillar['lessons'];
        }
    }
}

// $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
// get the current url.
$current_path = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; 
// $current_path = '/pillar1-lesson1/';
$current_path = getPath($current_path);
$pillarCurrent = $current_path['pillar'];
$lessonCurrent = $current_path['lesson'];

$lessons_nav = getLessonNav($pillars, $pillarCurrent, $lessonCurrent);

get_header(); ?>

    <style>
        .pillars .top-bar .name {
            background-color: #a54399;
            border-radius: 29px;
            margin: 0 5px;
            float: left;
        }
        .pillars .top-bar .name a {
            color: #ffffff !important;
            line-height: 17px !important;
            padding: 4px 15px !important;
        }
        .pillars .top-bar .name.current {
            background-color: #e99504;
        }
        .pillars .top-bar .name:hover {
            background-color: #e99504;
        }
        .entry-title {
            display: none;
        }
        section.content_wrap.row .top-bar {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        .nav_wrap{
            background-color:#ffffff;
        }
        nav.lessons-bar {
            background-color: #7a7a7a;
            height: 35px;
        }
        .lessons-bar ul.title-area {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .lessons-bar li.name {
            float: left;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        .lessons-bar li.name a{
            color: #ffffff !important;
        }
        .pillars .lessons-bar .name.current,
        .pillars .lessons-bar .name:hover       {
            background-color: #008c99;
        }

        /* learn dash style */
        .entry-content #learndash_lesson_topics_list > div {
            border: none;
            border-radius: 0;
            box-shadow: none;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .entry-content #learndash_lesson_topics_list .topic {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            margin-bottom: 20px;    
        }
        .learndash_topic_dots .topic-header {
            background-color: #ccf6f4;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .entry-content .learndash .topic-notcompleted span {
            background: none;
            padding-left: 0px; 
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            color: #444444;
            font-size: 22px;
        }

    </style>
        <div id="content" class="medium-12 large-12 columns pillars" role="main">

        <div class="nav_wrap row">

            <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar data-options="mobile_show_parent_link: true">
                <ul class="title-area">
                <?php foreach ($pillars as $key => $tile) {  ?>
                    <li class="name <?php if (strpos($tile['url'], $pillarCurrent)) echo 'current' ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $tile['url'] ?>"><?php echo $tile['name'] ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>   

            <nav class="lessons-bar" data-topbar data-options="mobile_show_parent_link: true">
                <ul class="title-area">
                <?php if ($lessons_nav) foreach ($lessons_nav as $key => $tile) {  ?>
                    <li class="name <?php if (strpos($tile['url'], $lessonCurrent)) echo 'current' ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $tile['url'] ?>"><?php echo $tile['name'] ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>   

        </div>


            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php comments_template( 'comments.php', true ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What I am trying to edit is the nav with the class "lessons-bar"

Comment: can you provide us with some code so that we can take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by putting a class on your main container page if it's currently on a certain page. There's a WP built in function where it can tell you what page you currently are.

You can try doing like this one:

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site <?php if(is_page( 'lesson-1-page' )) echo 'wide-content';?>">
```

I believe that starting element can be found on `header.php`, you try and edit that there.

Then on your css add this :

```
.wide-content {
  width: "specify-your-wider-width-here";
}
```

resources: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page